# FileGDB write support for GDAL/OGR in macOS

Tags: gdal, homebrew

I am using macOS Mojave and Homebrew with latest update. 
I have tried to install gdal 3.0.1 and filegdb plugins via homebrew-osgeo4mac tap as below:

```
brew tap osgeo/osgeo4mac
brew install osgeo-gdal
brew install osgeo-gdal-filegdb
```

After complete, I could not find FileGDB on the listed format after checking via `ogrinfo —formats`
only OpenFileGDB on the list with read-only support

How to enable write support for FileGDB in macOS?
I have follow various solution that already answered in this forum with no success.

For comparison, I installed GDAL+FileGDB plugin from gisinternals repo in Windows 10, and FileGDB on the list with write support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I solved my own problem. So its because gdal and filegdb has different version (v3.0.1 vs v2.4.1) and not symlink correctly to `/usr/local/lib/gdalplugins/3.0`

What I did, change line 4 in [osgeo-gdal-filegdb.rb](https://github.com/OSGeo/homebrew-osgeo4mac/blob/master/Formula/osgeo-gdal-filegdb.rb)
with latest gdal 3.0.1 link from 
[osgeo-gdal.rb](https://github.com/OSGeo/homebrew-osgeo4mac/blob/master/Formula/osgeo-gdal.rb) in line 23
Then do `brew upgrade osgeo-gdal-filegdb`

[image: rw enabled for filegdb]